# JavaScript : How to get Coordinates from JSON array within dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

how do I get the x- and y-coordinates from this JSON response:

```
{
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 4326,
        "latestWkid": 4326
     },
     "candidates": [
     {
         "address": "Berlin",
         "location": {
             "x": 13.376910000000066,
             "y": 52.516040000000032
          },
     }
}
```

Should I use JSON.parse? Don't know how to handle an array that is inside an array that is inside a dictionary which is inside an array.

Comment: you may try:  array[i].candidates[j].location.x and same for y. [i] is your array index, j is the index for candidates. You need nested loops.

Comment: it depends on your data structure. you schould describe it more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your variable name is `data`.

If you want to print the first index

```
console.log(data.candidates[0].location.x)
console.log(data.candidates[0].location.y)
```

If you want to access all of it

```
for (var i = 0; i< data.candidates.length; i++){
    console.log(data.candidates[i].location.x)
    console.log(data.candidates[i].location.y)
}
```

If your `data` is an array

Then

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data[j].candidates.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[j].candidates[i].location.x)
    console.log(data[j].candidates[i].location.y)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review the documentation on [indexed collections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections).

In any case, you can access the coordinates as follows:

```
var response = {
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 4326,
    "latestWkid": 4326
  },
  "candidates": [{
    "address": "Berlin",
    "location": {
      "x": 13.376910000000066,
      "y": 52.516040000000032
    }
  }]
};

var coordinates = response["candidates"][0]["location"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this string in to JS object when you use `JSON.parse`.

Then it is a matter of which object is inside which.

Let's say you are praising your string in to a variable names `jobs`.

```
var jobs = JSON.parse(myDataObject)
```

Following lines will show you how to access each part of the object now.

```
console.log(jobs.spatialReference.wkid) //4326
console.log(jobs.candidates[0]location.x) //13.376910000000066
```

Notice that if you have said

```
console.log(jobs.candidates[0])
```

This is going to return the whole object

```
{
    "address": "Berlin",
    "location": {
      "x": 13.376910000000066,
      "y": 52.516040000000032
    }
  }
```